# converting a mysql_row to an integer

Tags: c++, c

is there an easy way to convert a row obtained from a result of a query into an integer in C/C++...

eg

```
//iterating over each row of the result
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL)
{
 printf("%s\n",row[0]);
}
```

output

```
100
101
102
```

mysql_row is of the type string so i can easyily display..but my problem is i want to convert that to an intger so that i can add all the column values of the result

`i.e 100+101+102`

i guess using sscanf helps but dont knw how to use it in this situation

Answer (score 2):

use `atoi(row[index])`

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/

Comment: tried that..didnt work :( gives a huge number(most probably junk value)

Answer (score 0):

> "mysql_row is of the type string so i can easyily display"

Erm, don't do that.

`MYSQL_TYPE_LONG` is what you want, which makes the result an int.

**EDIT:** Based on the comment below. I hadn't used the C API in years so I just looked it up.  It's ... rather limited as compared to say, Oracle's C API. Everything is returned as a string in your case, so you *have* to convert it yourself.

As mentioned in the other answers, if you're using C++ you can use `atoi`. If that's not working ... you've got some other issue (wrong column, perhaps).

Comment: my result includes strings as well as numbers(stored as string) in every row,anyways the number part is what i want.how do i use MYSQL_TYPE_LONG in getting my result?,could you please post an example, i couldn't find any